# jQuery to prevent form from submit does not work - asp classic

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am calling a function on submit to check whether required uploads are done or not and if there are no uploads in the database, the form should not be submitted.

By using alert , I can see that my checkuploads.asp is returning the correct value and it is displaying the alert that data was not found but it is not preventing the form from submitting.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#Save').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkuploads.asp?value=" + $('#RequestNo').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === "Not Found") {
                    alert("the data was not found");
                    data.preventDefault();
                    window.history.back();
                    return false;
                } else
                if (data === "Found") {
                    alert("the data was found");
                    alert(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `ajax` request, the response will offcourse take some time, before that the form is getting submitted. So, you need to `return false;` after ajax call.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#Save').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkuploads.asp?value=" + $('#RequestNo').val(),
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === "Not Found") {
                    alert("the data was not found");
                    //data.preventDefault();//Remove this un-necessary line
                    window.history.back();
                    //return false;//Remove this too. It is un-necessary
                } else
                if (data === "Found") {
                    alert("the data was found");
                    alert(data);
                    //Replace the form id with correct one
                    ("#myForm").submit();//Add this line
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the complete example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form id="myForm" action="/my-listener">
                <input type="text" name="RequestNo" id="RequestNo" />
                <input type="button" id="Save" value="Save" />
            </form>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#Save').click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checkuploads.asp?value=" + $('#RequestNo').val(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data === "Not Found") {
                                alert("the data was not found");
                                window.history.back();
                            } else if (data === "Found") {
                                alert("the data was found");
                                alert(data);
                                $("#myForm").submit();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to your code snippet the best method will be to get the forma element inside `if (data === "Found") {...}` and submit it. eg. `$('#myForm').submit()`

Comment: “if there are no uploads in the database, the form should not be submitted.”
 Now if there ARE uploads then the form should be submitted. So how can one allow the form to submit in such case?

Comment: I have updated answer with working example. Hopefully it helps you!!

Comment: Welcome. You can accept it as answer, if worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
         $(window).load(function() {
                $('#Save').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "checkuploads.asp?value=" + $('#RequestNo').val(),
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data === "Not Found") {
                                alert("the data was not found");
                                data.preventDefault();
                                window.history.back();
                                return false;
                            } else
                            if (data === "Found") {
                                alert("the data was found");
    window.location.replace( "checkuploads.asp?value=" + $('#RequestNo').val()); // you can chanbge url as per your need
// in case of form use
$('#form').submit();
                                alert(data);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Comment: Use window.location.replace( "checkuploads.asp?value=" + $('#RequestNo').val()) in (data === "found")

Comment: tried it but I have many fields to be submitted to another asp page. checkuploads.asp is just to check the uploads, the actual form submits to another asp with more than 50 different fields.

Comment: use $('#form').submit(); to submit that form.